# Cuke4Duke on Grails

Tags: ruby, grails, groovy, cucumber, bdd

Ok, so I've got a grails app here.

On a previous project we used cucumber alongside grails with our step definitions working in ruby.
It was ok, but it would be nice if we could write our defs in groovy, same scripting language we're using everywhere else.

If anyone's ever done it before, or knows how I could get it running, let me know.  I've seen a few plugins that don't appear to work with 1.3.7

Is there not some way for me to just put jruby, cuke4duke in the BuildConfig dependencies and just write a scripts/Cucumber.groovy to invoke it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/thetrav/grails-cucumber

Looks like someone else had already built a cuke4duke plugin, my modification causes it to fail on errors and allocates a large permgen space for it to use.

We're now using groovy step definitions (just put .groovy files in ${project_root}/features/step_definitions) and geb to drive the browser, all seems to work ok

Comment: Does this works on the current 2.0.3 version of Grails? It's the project under active development? Are there alternatives?

Comment: I'd recommend against using this particular plugin.  While it got that project over the line, cuke4duke has been superseded by the vastly superior cucumber-jvm.